# Where do files created save in Eclipse? New File Not Found Exception?

Tags: java, file, io

On a project I'm working on, we have to create a file and save certain strings to it. While I can create the file without any errors, I'm not sure where I can access it, as it is supposed to save in the "lib" folder, but it's not there.
[EDIT] the code now throws a "File Not Found Exception", and I'm not sure why

Here is my code for the creation of the file:

```
System.out.println("What is the name of your input file?");
String name = console.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is the name of your output file?");

String outName = console.nextLine();
Scanner input  = new Scanner(new File("GazillionSongs.txt"));
File out       = new File(outName);
Scanner output = new Scanner(new FileReader(outName));

//checks for input and output file, creates a prinstream based on new file
PrintStream outPrint = new PrintStream(out);
```

Comment: are u able to successfully run this program?

Comment: actually, it throws a File not found exception, but I created the file in the File out = new File(outName) option right?

Comment: They'll (most likely) be created I the "current working" directory, you can use something like `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to find out where that currently is

Comment: If your lib folder was at say C:/lib then you could do this:

Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:/lib/GazillionSongs.txt"));

Comment: @javaBeginner : No you didn't just created a new file. It takes an absolute path or relative path. You have not given any of these just the name of file and hence JVM can't find the directory of this. If you give just the directory and then give name, it will be able to create that and also for `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("GazillionSongs.txt"));` as explained give a path not name. Check the constructor of File() with arguments . you will know

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new file and save data to it from another file you need to follow this :

```
    File f = new File(
            "System or War path of your target file. Since file doesn't "
            + "exist you need to give location of folder where you want to create file");
                //this is your outName
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

PS : This is one of the basic solution

Comment: Why would the code I wrote above throw a File Not Found Exception, when I've created the file before I use the print stream?

Comment: check my comment in your question

Comment: how would I designate the directory if I want the file to be in the "lib" folder?

Comment: use System.properties or use a  predefined variable or as simple as 

`StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(ResourceLoaderUtility.class     .getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()     .toString());
s = new StringBuffer(s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("/lib")));
s.append("/classes").append("/gsp_truststrore_cacerts.jks");
   File f = new File(new URI(s.toString()))`

This worked for me. You can check what you want to keep s.

Comment: `ResourceLoaderUtility` is you class where you are writing this piece of code.

Comment: in case this solves your  problem please don't hesitate to vote up & accept answer. please